# How to allow parents to register children but still record their own info

Tags: civievent, wordpress, webform-civicrm

For class registrations, parents register their children, but they don't need to register themselves (because they won't be attending the class). Has anyone come up with a way to handle this, that allows us to capture the parent and students as regular contacts, vs resorting to a profile of custom participant fields?

I've looked into the [Youth Registration](https://github.com/sgladstone/com.pogstone.youthregistration) extension, but there are open issues stating that it isn't compatible with 4.4 (and we're on 4.5.8).

Edit: Webform-CiviCRM is Drupal-specific, so is not an option for this organization.

Comment: Lesley, How do you manage the payment ? I have the same problem and use the same process, but the payment is requested before children are registered with pertaining options. Would webform bring a solution to this problem ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3552)

Comment: sorry if i gave you the thumbs down and you don't have enough points to make a comment. It may be better to ask yours as a separate question and reference this one. If you do, then please try and explain the workflow as clearly as possible. We have provide several webform based solutions for educational processing so yes it may be what you need. If i understand you need payment before the full application then it can still be managed via webform if you have the right type of payment processor. and using webform helps by letting you create Activities as well as contributions.

Comment: but better on a separate question i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten the desired result by creating a custom WP page to capture parent information and the [jQuery Repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) plugin to capture unlimited students and registrations. It displays checkboxes for all future events of a given Event Type. The form posts to a PHP page that creates the contacts, relationships, and event registrations via the API. I'm still playing with it, but you can [get the code here](https://github.com/narayanis/civicrm_wp_multi_student_registration). The client takes deposits and multiple payments for the student camps, so there is no contribution or payment code involved at this point.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Drupal, [Webform-CiviCRM Integration](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) will handle your scenario pretty easily. It allows registering any number of participants for any number of events on a single form.

You may also want to e-mail Sarah Gladstone, the author of the Youth Registration extension, what she uses instead - but I'm pretty sure they use Webform-CiviCRM integration these days.

Comment: I've used that module for Drupal-based orgs, but the folks I'm helping right now run on Wordpress so we're tied to core functionality and CMS-independent extensions. Wordpress doesn't have a plugin remotely as powerful as Webform.

Comment: I  formally abandoned my YouthRegistraion extension that I sponsored. Now I am using WebForm and the WebForm-CiviCRM modules.  My recipe for handling youth registration: https://civicrm.org/blog/sarahgladstone/recipe-for-handling-youth-registration-with-civicrm

Answer (score 7):

Contributing or sponsoring upgrades to the youth-registration extension seems like a good option for you. The extension has already been written and seems to need minimal maintenance to get it working with the latest version of CiviCRM.

Short of that, your current options are limited. You could set up your registration form in such a way that the child's information gets entered as the participant, with the parent's billing info and some custom data fields to enter parental and emergency contact info. This would not create contacts in the db for the adults but at least the information would exist.

Answer (score 4):

I use WebForm-CiviCRM integration module (https://civicrm.org/extensions/webform-civicrm-integration) for my school/youth registration requirements. (I had sponsored the creation of the youth registration extension back when webform-civicrm integration was not as robust)

Answer (score 3):

As you note, there is an open issue for the Youth Registration extension relating to 4.4.0.  However, there was a PR merged in Sept 2014 to make it work on 4.4.6.

I don't know whether those changes are enough to make it work on 4.5.8, but if WebForm-CiviCRM is not an option for you, then it would be worth trying the current version.

Answer (score 3):

In order to register children for a class, I added custom profiles, using custom fields in CiviCRM (See under 'Customize Data and Screens'). The core registrant data is the parent's (as they're paying for the class), and the custom profiles allow for up to 3 children's names, ages, gender, school they attend, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a WordPress specific question I believe these sorts of forms can be built using the Caldera forms integration for CiviCRM.