# Adding contacts to memberships

Tags: wordpress, civimember, 4.6.10

The standard contribution form for signing up for household memberships doesn't allow the person signing up to add additional people to the membership. It would be nice if the form had a page (or other affordance) after the initial information form to allow them to add additional names and email addresses. This page would fit between the initial page and the verify page. How is this typically handled? Right now the workflow forces an admin to manually edit the relationships tab for a household contact. I could add custom fields (name, email) to the member sign up for this, but how would you pass this data along to the database as relationship contacts?

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Drupal, Webform with Webform Civicrm Integration could do this. It allows you to have users create any number of contacts, along with relationships between contacts.

Comment: True, but P a u l has tagged his question WordPress.

Comment: Well then, I wasn't very helpful was I? Sorry about that, P a u l.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I missed a tag... :)

Comment: I couldn't figure out Drupal. The rest of the folks would therefore have no hope.

Comment: Hi Paul, would the answer here prove helpful in any way? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/634/105 If so, I'll post it formally with a small explanation as an answer to this question.

Comment: That's legit. Drupal has a steep learning curve, in my experience.